# Custom Scrollbar shows in Chromium and Safari, but not Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a custom scrollbar that appears in Chromium and Safari, but it will not show up in Chrome... makes no sense! Does anyone know what may be causing this?

*EDIT* may also be worth noting that the scrollbar USED to appear in Chrome just fine... maybe some new Chrome update broke it?

Here is a link to the site (scrollbar is at the bottom): [www.missingnewyork.com/store](http://www.missingnewyork.com/store)

And here is the CSS for the scrollbar:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 1%;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: white;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: not advised to use custom scrollbars, as its behaviour is unstable between versions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Comment: thank you for this. any work around? :-(

Comment: The CSS itself has no problem in Chrome version 85.0.4183.102 (macOS 10.15.6): https://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/Lqmek69r/ . In fact, the scrollbar works in your website, if you change the body height to a larger value, say 10000px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it should look? (smaller maybe)

If that is the case it's probably because of the `height: 1%;`. CSS doesn't know very well what is the % for heights, it's better to not use it. Try to use `vh` of some fixed value.

[image]

Comment: PERFECT. I can't believe that was the issue. Thanks!